# MSAL iOS integration issue

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, cocoapods, azure-ad-msal

I am installing MSAL pod to integrate AZURE AD into my iOS project.

pod install works fine and it installed MSAL 1.1.2. But when I open my project and trying to build it, it's showing 6 compile time errors.

Use of undeclared identifier 'MSIDSSOExtensionGetAccountsRequest'

All errors are related to above.
Please suggest what's wrong with my project.

I am using Xcode 10.3(due to some project dependencies). MSAL sample project itself is not working on Xcode 10.3 but working on Xcode 11.3
Is there any specific version of MSAL I need to use with Xcode 10.3?

Comment: have you imported the framework? `import MSAL`? cleaned your project? please explain what you have tried so far

Comment: These errors are showing in library files itself.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running?  What is the base SDK for your app (not the target)?  Those symbols are related to the enterprise SSO component in the Microsoft Authenticator app.

Comment: Xcode 10.3 (can't use higher version due to some dependencies), Base SDK iOS, target 11.3.

Answer (score 0):

Versions of MSAL for iOS after 1.0.7 require the iOS 13 SDK.

Since you are limited to the iOS 12 SDK, you will need to specify version 1.0.7 in your Podfile.

Comment: I had changed the dependencies and used Xcode 11. Thanks for the response.